# How can I add events in child component in listview? Is it possible to add event in listview?

Tags: react-native

' In My listview two component:first,second.
    In the second there are map function return third (array elements).
    How can I pass and the click event in the first, second, third & inner. For comments & sub comments in post. In the bellow updateComments is not working. And one thing, WallUpdates is also child component.'

```
class WallUpdates extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.updateComments = this.updateComments.bind(this);
  }
  updateComments(){
    alert("updatecommentPost");
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <View>
      <Text>
      {this.props.allPost}
      </Text>
      <ListView
          dataSource={this.props.dataSource} renderRow={this.renderMovie} style={styles.listView}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderMovie(list) {
    var commentNodes = list.comment.map((item, i) => {
      console.log(item);
      console.log(item.commentcontent);
      return (<Comments key={item.cid} comment={item.commentcontent} />);
    });
    //

    return (
      <View style={styles.container} >
        <Text style={styles.year}>{list.postcontent + '\n\n'}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.updateComments}>
          <View style={styles.buttonsmall}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonsmallText}>comments!</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {commentNodes}
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed - renderMovie(list)  to    renderMovie = (list) =>   and  also change onPress={this.updateComments} to onPress={() => { this.updateMe() }} & this is working for me .